# Why was user12262 a.k.a shanu deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, user-accounts

Why was user12262 a.k.a shanu deleted?

His/Her last post was:

[Do any Hindu scriptures say that Hinduism is not a religion but simply a way of life?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22272/do-any-hindu-scriptures-say-that-hinduism-is-not-a-religion-but-simply-a-way-of)

Was it voluntary account deletion or was it a result of a mod action?

If latter, what did the user do to warrant account deletion?

Comment: I'm not sure whether revealing information about account deletions violates user privacy.  But if I find that moderators are allowed to, I'd be happy to tell you.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, it is a matter of privacy

Comment: Just few days back i received one notification saying- -40 user removed. And i was wondering who that user was. So, that's shanu. I liked this user a lot; his primary field of interest (or study) seemed to be Rig Veda. **@shanu if you are reading my message please come back.** We need more and more users like you.

Comment: @Rickross That's what triggered me to write this post. Agree, we need more users like shanu.

Comment: @sv. I think there was  some heated quarrel between shanu and another user which eventually resulted in shanu deleting his own account. Now, that is not acceptable to me. Let's hope shanu sees this post and changes his decision.

Comment: @Rickross Another user user9392 a.k.a AnuragSingh is also gone.

Comment: @sv. It is also same case of self deletion. I think he said he will come back.

Comment: @sv. I did not realize when his account got deleted.

Comment: @sv. As correctly predicted by Destroyer AnuragSingh is back. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/12826/anurag-singh?tab=profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was self deletion and reason is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the user accounts were deleted is a matter of privacy. These matters are put anonymous.

This is between the moderators and the users and revealing them is against the privacy of the user. They are considered private and not made public unless the user chooses to. This the policy of SE.

For references, [Why is it not possible to have more information about “User was removed”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155885/357396)

Comment: It is the official policy.. @sv.

Comment: Mods can reveal self deletions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Can the reason for deletion be made public?

Comment: @TheDestroyer hmmm. I heard from other moderators that the reasons will not be revealed unless the user wants to and it's private.

Comment: @NogShine Assuming a mod deletes a user in a fit of rage, do you want to find out what really happened or just keep quoting/repeating the official SE policy to yourself? I don't see any any harm in finding out why a user was deleted. [This MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/) is publicly listing all new users accounts who seem like spammers. Why aren't people worried about the "privacy" of these spammers?

Comment: @sv. 1.Mods don't delete accounts at any time in a rage or anything. They do it on a request or there is anything illegal or against the rules. 2.You said they are 'spammers'. Do you think spam is allowed on SE?

Comment: @NogShine 'Mods don't delete accounts at any time in a rage or anything.' - How do you know? Have you served as a mod on any SE site? Have you ever encountered abuse of power? Your favorite mod suspended my MSE account in a fit of rage because someone's flag "interrupted" him when he was "busy" preparing dinner on a Friday night and his "precious" time was wasted.

Comment: Suspension and user deletion are not the same. Suspensions are done when there is something against the rules. Your user account was suspended on MSE you know the reason pretty well than me. So, I won't comment on it. I know this because I have talked to many mods regarding this one and all said the same.  Self deletion doesn't happen like that. It only happens if the user asks.