# User was removed

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users

An actively voting user got deleted today. Many people have reputations loss due to that. Which User got removed? & also Why (if anyone knows)?
From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155885/163449) meta post, it appears that the user may have requested for deletion of their profile (if not sock puppet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was user12262 a.k.a shanu deleted?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1034/why-was-user12262-a-k-a-shanu-deleted) and also [Why is it not possible to have more information about “User was removed”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155885/357396).

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, IMO it's better to close other way around, because this Qn is broader. However, it would be great, if we can close this Qn as duplicate of the main meta you have linked. I requested for that feature, which didn't work out: [Allowing straightforward duplicates to be linked from main meta to specific meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276854/163449)

Comment: I don't think this is a broader question. The reasons are just the same for each and every user. Why to make this a community wiki? . It only gives rise to speculations instead of facts ((which happened under previous question) The deleted user name is not revealed because of anonymity of the votes cast. It is same as knowing who voted on your posts. If user has left the site after contributing, then we should respect their decision. Discussing about them is against their privacy and isn't necessary to us. That wouldn't give healthy outcome. That makes this topic POB too.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, requested community-wiki so that the question can be edited in future by anyone, who intends to know any deletion. Yes, I understand you point of privacy. However, just IMO every real person is already protected behind a username and an image. Moreover, hard deletion may not surely prove on who got deleted. Since this user was an active voter, I got interested to know who that was. There is no compulsion for Mods/anyone to reveal.

Comment: I have already lost about 750 points this month :D with 3 users being removed. I know who the previous 2 were but not sure about the user who was removed yesterday. @iammilind

Comment: Why is knowing who voted to you and which user was deleted important?  Isn't it same knowing who upvoted or downvoted on posts?

Comment: Knowing who voted for us is not important.. but knowing which user was deleted is important.. because we are a community, we are friends, we interact with each other.. so it's a natural curiosity.. why do u think it's not an important  inquiry? @User9125

Comment: Does that make any difference @Rickross ? Is that natural curiosity helping the site in anyway? Votes will not be restored, user will not return. From whom do you expect the answer? Deleted user or the moderator? A CM has clarified that he would not say the name because it is not important. Many users come and go. Collecting info of each and every user who joined and left is not a constructive discussion.

Comment: What's really the purpose of this meta post? I only see this post showing to other readers **how bad this community in retaining users "of interest"**. Are there any possible constructive outcomes come from this post? If you want to discuss/gossip about the reason, then do it elsewhere, not SE.

Comment: @User9125, We are not discussing the deletion of the user[s] in the main site. In this meta sites, there are many posts, which are on friendly manner and curiosity basis - i.e. asking people's faith, interests, books etc.. Moreover, we are not interrogating anyone Mods/CMs/Users to answer this Qn. Anyone who is like minded may answer it. As stated below the answer of CM's in a comment, if we hard press the customs of SO/MSE here then this post may not be "useful". But we are not always looking for "usefulness", are we?

Comment: @iammilind Even meta sites have scope and what to discuss. Discussion about users especially "deleted users" is not useful. If we are  not looking for usefulness, then chat is better place to talk about it rather than meta. Meta should have some quality discussions. This is not promoting good faith. I have seen a couple of user friendly discussions on this meta and many on other meta but other metas don't have discussions about deleted users. They close them as dupes or opinion based. There is already a canonical post. Discussion about every user is not useful.

Comment: Does that make any difference Rickross ? Is that natural curiosity helping the site in anyway?--- Helping the site? Do we do everything to help the site here? We can't be even curious to know which of our friends was removed? If the Q is not that constructive ur undue prolonging the discussion is even less so. I understand that you can't think like the way some of us do because u are not an active member. You are a member over 1 year now and i am seeing u for the 1st time here in these comments. I also don't understand why should i be replying to each of ur comments. @User9125

Comment: I've removed the first part of your post, because it is highly inappropriate for Meta. We do not track which users delete their accounts. We need to respect the privacy of users who decide to leave and accept the fact that they decided to delete their profile. Keeping records of who left and when is not an activity you should ever be focused on.

Comment: I am late in the discussion  due to some reason. But Shall we now  discuss about regaining those points somehow?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Sure. Points will not be regained. Well, that was a short discussion.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not going to give any details in this particular case, but the three main reasons for a user to be removed are:

1. An automated process [removed an abandoned account](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/16/when-is-an-account-abandoned/); this process was [discontinued in May 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146452).
2. A moderator or [community manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) deleted a user's account because the user abused the site without making positive contributions.
3. A user asked for their account to be deleted.

Comment: I can understand about "why" part; but Why is it not possible to know "which" user was removed?

Comment: @iammilind: How would knowing that information help? In any case, I no longer remember the name of the user who was deleted.

Comment: As rightly stated in [this comment](https://goo.gl/535rxW), this small community is more associated on religious grounds. It's a general curiosity for knowing about each other. So far, in my SO or other SE profiles, I have seen many instances of small reputation loss & didn't care. This time when I saw -60 (still small), I just checked other users' reputations and most of them had much bigger losses. That intensified my curiosity about who was this user? I felt that, I surely would have interacted with them. If you keep applying SO/MSE equations/rules here, then you may find this post useless.

Comment: @iammilind: I spent a good deal of time participating on a [very small site](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). If someone's account was deleted, we tended to know it was coming one way or another. If we didn't know . . . well, I'm not sure that user was so important to the community after all.