# Allow account "deactivation", instead of irreversible "deletion"

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, user-interface, deleted-accounts

Like Facebook, there can be a feature of deactivation of an SE profile, where the account is not deleted permanently but deactivated until next login for activation. All the user data is restored once the account is reactivated.

Comment: May I ask why do we need this feature? Is deactivation per-account or per-site? What's the difference between inactive user, deleted user, and just not being logged in? If it's per-account, then you can just browse the site while being logged out.

Comment: This feature should be implemented network wide. I don't see need for our single site. Why not post it on main meta for more opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good feature**.
I support it.

One strong use case is that an "Inactive user" will not cause reputation loss to anyone. It happened [recently in our site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1269/1049) to several users.

Additionally the username while deactivating may remain as it is, if the user chooses to. However this username will not link to any profile due to deactivation.
Upon reactivation, everything would be restored like before.

---

Related meta:
[Deactivating my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160097/163449)

Comment: Inactive account will not be deleted. That is an outdated answer which needs to be updated.  User deletions happen through out the network. Similarly reputation losses also. If we are concerned for our reputation, it doesn't seem good. We have to just let things happen in the case of user deletion.

Comment: Millind you can post on main meta if want.

Comment: @Rohit. I personally find main meta as "cruel". Some big cats are sitting their with main purpose of using their downvotes. More downvotes means hung profile (can't ask Qn for sometime). Yet, If we get a good response here then I can post there.

Comment: Yup. I agree. Nowadays, people do not lose any chance by which they they can satisfy their ego. condescendence everywhere.

Comment: Well, iammilind, I don't find main meta cruel at all. Some downvotes on a post and calling a site cruel? Downvote on feature request means not useful feature. Discussing among ourselves about a fature which doesn't get enough audience and discussion is not useful. Just some upvoted posts. Per site meta feature requests should be used for getting site specific features and not features like these IMO.  I downvoted this question because the request made is not clear and you have intervened to clear the OP's request. OP should be clear first.