# Call out to Mods! Why no action from almost 3 years?

Tags: discussion, moderators, community, moderation, help-center

There seems null meta activity from mods these days or at least null interaction with the community.

No action by any mod on the following series of posts:

**1. To remove `mythology` tag:**

- [New Community Consensus on use of Mythology Tag](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1015/93) (**No action on this from almost 3 years**)
- [Mods - When are we going to remove mythology tag?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1646/93) (**New post to follow up on this, but no response**)
- [Apparently the term 'Mleccha' is offensive to 'foreigners', but the term 'mythology' is not offensive to scriptures of 'natives'?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1834/93)

**2. To make word `Mleccha` as offensive when used against a person(s):**

- [Is it fine to use a derogatory word like Mleccha on this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1715/93)

**3. Discussions to make `cross-religion posts off-topic`:**

- [How much of cross religion questions should we allow?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/93)
- [Are Buddha's origin and life going to be a nod to cross religious questions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/93)
- [Questions asking whether Hinduism is unique with respect to a particular feature?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1712/93)
- [Is comparison of a topic with other religions on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/93)

**My question is to mods**:

Why there is no conclusion on any of the above posts or update in the help page or approval of flags at least as per what community has decided to go with?

It feels like the community is just playing around here with no conclusion whatsoever. If this continues, people will leave this site as many of them are getting offended by something that should be addressed. We have to keep updating our help page to address the concerns of the community members.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't we answering on meta?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/why-arent-we-answering-on-meta)

Answer (score 5):

> **Q.** There seems null meta activity from mods these days or at least null interaction with the community.

The title of the question *(Why no action from almost 3 years?)* is misleading. **Flags are being handled on almost daily basis**. 219 flags have been handled in last quarter (including 106 in last month (including 55  in last week)). This flag handling results in deletion of problematic posts (QA and comments), adding post-notices when required and other things.

> **Q.** No action by any mod on the following series of posts:

This would be more specific and partially true call but it would not be proper to say that no action has been taken by moderators from 3 years. Let me reply to the three major issue addressed in the question one by one.

1. **Mythology tag**

   Yes, if we consider top voted answers including the accepted one, it seems community is agree with purge of mythology tag. In August 2019 I [proposed another way](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1689/277) but finally we (mods) concluded to remove the tag completely but community moderators can't purge a tag completely, it needs [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/260388) or probably developers to accomplish the task.

   <s>3 Years ago</s> In Aug 2019 we had discussed with other mods and also pinged CMs if we can remove the tag completely. We first need to retag all those questions which are tagged only with [mythology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology). We edited some questions to apply this fix but some questions couldn't get fixed and hence we didn't accomplish the task of purging the tag. Anyway, we will again try to resolve this issue soon.
2. **Usage of word Mleccha**

   You [have answered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1727/277) the question well. Yes, flag us if you find word is used in offensive way at anywhere or inform if you flag is declined. Can you clarify what action is pending or rejected (if any)?
3. **Scope of cross-religions questions:**

   The [question you've mentioned](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/277) is posted by mod to take feed-back from community. I have discussed this issue with mods of other religious sites. It is under consideration. After concluding how such questions should be handled on Hinduism Stack Exchange, an answer will be posted soon to get the proposed way be reviewed by community and then this Meta QA will be added to the [list](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/277) of [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: Sorry Pandya.. I kept it strong so you guys can provide update. Most of us were not aware of the above info you provided. There were chaos of misinterpretation among the community members. I know no mod is inactive from the past 3 years :P. Do please try to interact with community members and if possible create decree (meta post) if misinterpretations are getting stronger.

Comment: For the #2, can we update the help center or FAQ?

Comment: "Flags are being handled on almost daily basis. 219 flags have been handled in last quarter" - I think OP is talking about 'null meta activity' i.e., why is there no response to meta questions like [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1845/2995) and [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/was-my-question-unfairly-deleted) especially those that concern mod actions?

Comment: "In Aug 2019 we had discussed with other mods and also pinged CMs if we can remove the tag completely. We first need to retag all those questions which are tagged only with mythology." - why was this not communicated to the rest of the community? I saw some recent activity from mods where 'mythology' tag was removed e.g., [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/36394/revisions) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/26940/revisions). Again, why is this not communicated through a separate meta post/announcement? Why are users left guessing what's happening on the main site?

Answer (score 2):

I am agreeing to this statement of OP

> It feels like the community is just playing around here with no
>   conclusion whatsoever. If this continues, ***people will leave this site
>   as many of them are getting offended by somethings that should be
>   addressed.***

Sensing this type of situation long back, I had posted a question - [Why is Hinduism SE not expanding?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/3869), way back in November 2015.  Thereafter, I left this site for some time, feeling frustrated.

Even after returning in May 2019, I had found the situation in a much worse stage.  Many old timers  are no where to be found now.

---

The following are my observations:

- Moderators are almost dormant
- Quality of questions has been deteriorating
- Site has been dominated by a few people, with ulterior motives
- accounts of members are being removed arbitrarily

---

If this situation continues, sooner or later, I doubt,  even my account may also will be removed.

Good luck to all

Comment: "accounts of members are being removed arbitrarily" what do you mean by that? Is someone removing accounts of some members or they themselves removing their accounts?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: who else can remove accounts other than moderators?

Comment: User himself can remove their accounts. Removal initiation only happens from users.  Moderators can only suspend for some time period.

Comment: namaskaram @srimannarayanakv gaaru, it's very likely those users are self-evicting themselves out of frustration. This site is an uncompromising site for new users as well as old. One has to ponder why it has not progressed beyond beta in the several years of its existence

Comment: One user was removed yesterday and one today. BTW, Mods don't remove the users.. the users themselves request for their accounts to be deleted .. and that's why their accounts get removed @srimannarayanakv

Comment: I am not interested in the technical aspects of removal.  If it is not removal may be it is suspension for shorter or longer periods or permanent suspension.  This site is running at the whims and fancies of a few persons, with prejudices. It is a fact.  Good night my friend @Rickross

Comment: No .. user removal and user suspensions are different. When users are removed we actually come to know about it by seeing the reduction of reputation points in our profiles. But user suspensions don't result in any such reduction (or change ) in points. Usually, when users are removed, their votes are also gone with them (sometimes votes are retained though).. Good night @srimannarayanakv Also, Mods suspend users, but users (not Mods) decide themselves whether they want their accounts to be deleted or not.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv BTW, you can check this post out: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/user-was-removed